# Would questions like "I'm interested in learning Foo, recommend me some books, websites etc" be welcome here?

Tags: discussion, policy, community-wiki

Would questions like "I'm interested in learning Foo, recommend me some books, websites etc" be welcome here? Where Foo is field of mathematics of course.

I haven't seen any yet, but they aren't uncommon on Stackoverflow, so I think that they could appear here too. **EDIT** [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967/)'s one.

Also, should such questions be community wiki or not (assuming that we do decide to have them)?

Comment: see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/445/what-questions-should-be-community-wiki for a discussion of community wiki policy

Comment: there was a number of examples, AFAIR. e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533/what-is-the-best-book-for-studying-discrete-mathematics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, such questions should be allowed. But they should be community wiki.